# Why HasOneOrMany doesn't update relations on parent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

We are developing an e-commerce cart using Laravel 5.3, which has items. So our cart has a 1:n relationship to items.

When we add some product to cart using `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save()` it doesn't push the new item to our `$cart->items` collection, it has to be done manually using `Collection::push()` method.

We are asking this because the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::associate()` method does that, so we don't know if this is a bug.

Just for better understanding:

Now we need to do this:

```
$cart = Cart::first();

$cartItem = new CartItem();
$cartItem->quantity = 1;
$cartItem->base_price = 1;
$cartItem->paid_price = 1;

$cart->items()->save($cartItem);
print($cart->items->count()); # returns 0
$cart->items->push($cartItem);
print($cart->items->count()); # returns 1
```

What we want to do is this code above, and then be able to interate with our list (for example update order values), without calling other methods.

```
$cart = Cart::first();

$cartItem = new CartItem();
$cartItem->quantity = 1;
$cartItem->base_price = 1;
$cartItem->paid_price = 1;

$cart->items()->save($cartItem);
print($cart->items->count()); # returns 1
```

We are thinking on make a pull request because we saw the code and it can be done. But is it correct? Can we do that?

Duplicated from here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14719

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in the discussion on [this issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/12180). I have copied the comments I made on that issue here, in case that link goes away at some point.

Information on how relationship attributes are loaded:

> This is expected behavior. Once the relationship attribute for a model
>   instance is loaded, it will not be reloaded unless explicitly
>   reloaded.
>
> ```
> // relationship attribute lazy loaded here
> $blog->posts->count()
>
> $post = new Post(['title' => 'post title');
>
> // typo in OP; save() must be called on relationship method, not relationship attribute
> $blog->posts()->save($post);
>
> // relationship already loaded. Collection has not changed.
> $blog->posts->count(); // 0
>
> // however, call to database will reflect current count
> $blog->posts()->count(); // 1
>
> // reload the relationship attribute
> $blog->load('posts');
>
> // relationship collection refreshed; count of relationship attribute will reflect this
> $blog->posts->count(); // 1
> ```

Why the relationship attribute `Collection` is not updated when an item is added to the relationship:

> I think there's too much uncertainty to attempt modifying the
>   Collection. Even though you're relating the post to the blog through
>   the `posts()` relationship, there is no guarantee that the new post
>   should be loaded into the relationship attribute Collection in the
>   first place.
>
> Imagine, for example, if your relationship were defined like this
>   (silly example, but bear with me):
>
> ```
> // only get posts created before today
> public function posts() {
>     return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->where('created_at', '<', date('Y-m-d'));
> }
> ```
>
> Given this relationship, since the new post is created today, it would
>   be incorrect if it were simply injected into the existing lazy loaded
>   `$blog->posts` collection, because it does not meet the added where
>   condition. If you reload this relationship, the new post will still
>   not be in it.
>
> Another example would be this:
>
> ```
> // get the posts, newest first
> public function posts() {
>     return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
> }
> ```
>
> Given this relationship, if the new post is added to the end of the
>   existing loaded `$blog->posts` collection, it will be in the incorrect
>   order. You could argue that it could be added to the beginning, but
>   then it would be in the incorrect order if the relationship were
>   ordered ASC. You would have to parse the relationship query to try to
>   figure out where to add the item.
>
> Now, those are just simple examples. I'm sure there are plenty of very
>   complicated relationships out there where it would be impossible to
>   parse all the constraints and conditions in order to properly insert
>   the new item into the existing collection.
>
> The only real alternative to the existing functionality would be to
>   always force a reload of an existing loaded relationship whenever the
>   relationship is modified, however that could lead to some serious
>   performance issues. It seems best to make sure the developer knows
>   they need to explicitly reload the relationship if needed, rather than
>   to implicitly reload it, whether it is needed or not.